# How to use Razor syntax in ASP.NET Web Application (not MVC)

Tags: asp.net, razor

How does one create a .cshtml page in an ASP.NET web application? The option to choose Razor is obvious when using MVC - it appears when adding a view. But I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this in a plain ASP.NET Web Application. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an HTML file and rename it to CSHTML.

Although Razor pages don't appear in the Add New Item list, they work fine in normal web projects.

Comment: mine says no compiler is registered for .cshtml

Comment: @Maslow: You need to install MVC3.

Comment: it says I have it, it was installed 5 days ago in my programs and features section. version `3.0.20105.0`. also Mvc3 Tools update `3.0.20406.0`. and finally Asp.net web pages `1.0.20105.0`

Comment: Try installing or repairing VS SP1.